# Is there a way to get distinct count from table function

Tags: r

Below is the dataframe df.

```
ds
  a b
1 a f
2 a d
3 b g
4 b g
```

When i try with `table(ds$b,ds$a)`, I get

```
    a b
  d 1 0
  f 1 0
  g 0 2
```

But I need only distinct like below

```
    a b
  d 1 0
  f 1 0
  g 0 1
```

Is there a way to get it through table function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pmin` to set the range between 0 and 1.

```
pmin(table(ds$b,ds$a), 1)
#    a b
#  d 1 0
#  f 1 0
#  g 0 1
```

Or use `unique` before `table`:

```
table(unique(ds)[2:1])
#b   a b
#  d 1 0
#  f 1 0
#  g 0 1
```

Data:

```
ds  <- data.frame(a=c("a","a","b","b"), b=c("f","d","g","g"))
```

Comment: Perfect. May I know what pmin is doing here?

Comment: @DevP In this case it sets values larger than 1 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

At least one way to do it is:

```
ifelse(table(ds$b,ds$a) > 0, 1, 0)
    a b
  d 1 0
  f 1 0
  g 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ds %>% 
  distinct %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = b, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  a         f     d     g
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     1     0
#2 b         0     0     1
```